# Mongodb aggregate with joins with multiple keys statement

Tags: mongodb-query

Actually i am not trying to match two collection's . I am looking for match the field with secondary collection. I'll explain my problem clearly:
this is my primary collection "bags".which contains

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("568f43e08a9f71b70b22a694"),
            "bagNo" : "HBBN/00001/16",
            "category" : "Voluntary",
            "regNo" : "DNR/00001/16",
            "status": "Accepted"
    }, 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("568f4645fa0758af0e3fef26"), "bagNo" :"HBBN/00002/16", "category" : "Voluntary", "regNo" : "DNR/00002/16", "status": "Rejected" },

{ "_id" : ObjectId("568f4645fa4546gygfef26"), "bagNo" : "HBBN/00003/16", "category" : "Voluntary", "regNo" : "DNR/00003/16", "status": "Accepted" }
```

now my join collection "donor" contains

```
 {"donorType" : "H",
     "regNo" : "DNR/00001/16",
     "surName" : "pandey",
     "firstName" : "rakesh"}, 
{"donorType" : "C", "regNo" : "DNR/00002/16", "surName" : "pandey", "firstName" : "rakesh" },

{"donorType" : "C", "regNo" : "DNR/00003/16", "surName" : "pandey", "firstName" : "rakesh" }
```

from these two collections i want to get the accepted bags data from bags collection which having 'donortype' as 'H' in donor collection.Please let me know if it is possible.explain with some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine two collections, you could try to do it with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in aggregation.

```
donor.aggregation([
      // filter the `donortype` of `H`
      {$match: {donortype: 'H'}},
      // join with `bags` collection for the foreign key `regNo`, and put bags into `h_bags` result. 
      {$lookup: {
          from: "bags",
          localField: "regNo",
          foreignField: "regNo",
          as: "h_bags"
        }},
      // unwind the `h_bags` array
      {$unwind: '$h_bags'},
      // filter the status of bags is `Accepted`
      {$match: {'h_bags.status': 'Accepted'}}
   ]);
```

Comment: But i want only Accepted bags i.e.,  "status" as "Accepted" from bags collection. for that where should i keep condition in the above code. is it possible to write a statement for join collection only?

Comment: @SivaM, please see my updated answer. you can `$unwind` the result `u_bags` array hen filter it with `status` is `Accepted`

Comment: Thank you so much @Zangw. you solved my problem. one more question?.. can i join more than two collections.. if it is possible could you explain me how

Comment: @SivaM, for current mongo version, you cannot join more than two collections

Comment: Ok. Is there any third party npm  to do so

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your suggestions @zangw